# How to get correct indentation for new line after "if","try", etc... blocks on Intellij Idea?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, indentation

I started to use Idea after using Eclipse for years. Now I found some features of Idea very basically absent. One of them is this; I write an `if` or `try` and a curly bracket `{` then I push `Enter`, new line comes with the same indentation of `if`:

```
// some code...
if (someBoolean) {
// <- cursor comes here
    // <- not here
}
```

How can I make this correct, and write new line without starting to write an extra `tab`?

Edit: This happens on JavaScript files. No problem when using Java. I checked that there is no plugin available for "JavaScript Support" as it is mentioned in comments.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior with IntelliJ 2016.3.3 (works as expected). What version are you using and for what programming language? Do you have a plugin enabled for this language by chance?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I use it for Java and Javascript; and I have just realized that, for Java, it works as expected. But for JS, (as it offers Ultimate Edition) I suppose there is no  support for JS. Is it correct?

Comment: For me it works for both, Java and Javascript. Does the file get highlighted and has the file the JS icon in the project explorer (i.e. recognized as Javascript file)?

You can check under Settings > Editor > Code Style > JavaScript if everything there looks okay. Unfortunately I don't know the exact property  that is responsible for this intend, but you could also use the "Set from..." option on the top and copy the settings from Java.

Comment: Yes, it recognizes as JS file. But there is no JavaScript section under Code Style. There are Java, HTML, JSON and some more others but no JavaScript. Do I miss something?

Comment: Can you please check in Settings > Plugins if the `JavaScript Support` plugin is installed/enabled? Perhaps that is missing.

Comment: Thank you, there is no JavaScript Support plugin. I can't find it by browsing it either. I guess this matrix explains the situation: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html There is no JS support for Community Edition. Do you use Ultimate?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer but yes, I use the Ultimate version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, there is no JavaScript Support plugin. I can't find it by browsing it.

This matrix explains the situation: http://jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

There is no JavaScript support for Community Edition.